# Bootstrap datepicker format not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am looking at http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#format

```
    $('#manufacture-date-picker').datepicker({
        startView: 0,
        minViewMode: 0,
        format: "d M yyyy"
    }).datepicker('setUTCDate', new Date({{ task.manufactureDate() * 1000 }}));
```

I'm finding when I load the page the format is correct (ie. the timestamp that gets passed in gets converted to 4 Feb 2015 or whatever it may be), but as soon as I select a date from the date picker it changes to this format:

`02/04/2015`

Why is the format option not being saved?

Answer (score 0):

It should be 
`format:"dd/MM/yyyy"` rather than what you have included

Comment: Are you saying the slashes are required? Wouldn't it end up as `4/Feb/2015` instead of `4 Feb 2015`??

Comment: oh ok..!! if you would have given html too that would have been more understandable. anyways good you solved it!! :)